# libvipsのcopyコマンドでPDFを画像化する際に、注釈を表示させる方法を知りたい

Tags: pdf

#### やりたいこと

- libvipsの `vips copy`コマンドでPDFを画像化する際に、注釈を表示したい。
- レンダーはpdfiumを使用したい。

#### 試したコマンド

- libvipsをインストール

```
export PREFIX=/usr/local/vips
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PREFIX/lib/pkgconfig
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PREFIX/lib
export PATH=$PATH:$PREFIX/bin

WORKDIR=/usr/local/src
VIPS_URL=https://github.com/libvips/libvips/releases/download
PDFIUM_URL=https://github.com/bblanchon/pdfium-binaries/releases/download/chromium

PDFIUM_VERSION=5351
VIPS_VERSION=8.13.2

# 関連ライブラリをインストール
yum install -y \
    libpng-devel \
    poppler-glib-devel \
    glib2-devel \
    libjpeg-devel \
    expat-devel \
    zlib-devel \
    orc-devel \
    lcms2-devel \
    libexif-devel \
    libgsf-devel

# pdftoppm
yum install -y poppler-utils

cd $WORKDIR

## install PDFIUM
mkdir pdfium-$PDFIUM_VERSION \
  && cd pdfium-$PDFIUM_VERSION \
  && wget $PDFIUM_URL/$PDFIUM_VERSION/pdfium-linux-x64.tgz
mkdir -p $PREFIX/lib/pkgconfig \
  && cd $PREFIX \
  && tar xf $WORKDIR/pdfium-$PDFIUM_VERSION/pdfium-linux.tgz \
  && echo "prefix=$PREFIX" >> lib/pkgconfig/pdfium.pc \
  && echo "exec_prefix=\${prefix}" >> lib/pkgconfig/pdfium.pc \
  && echo "libdir=\${exec_prefix}/lib" >> lib/pkgconfig/pdfium.pc \
  && echo "includedir=\${prefix}/include" >> lib/pkgconfig/pdfium.pc \
  && echo "Name: pdfium" >> lib/pkgconfig/pdfium.pc \
  && echo "Description: pdfium" >> lib/pkgconfig/pdfium.pc \
  && echo "Version: $PDFIUM_VERSION" >> lib/pkgconfig/pdfium.pc \
  && echo "Requires: " >> lib/pkgconfig/pdfium.pc \
  && echo "Libs: -L\${libdir} -lpdfium" >> lib/pkgconfig/pdfium.pc \
  && echo "Cflags: -I\${includedir}" >> lib/pkgconfig/pdfium.pc

## install libvips
wget $VIPS_URL/v$VIPS_VERSION/vips-$VIPS_VERSION.tar.gz \
  && tar xf vips-$VIPS_VERSION.tar.gz \
  && cd vips-$VIPS_VERSION \
  && ./configure --prefix $PREFIX \
  && make V=0 \
  && make install
```

- PDFを画像化

```
vips copy intput.pdf[page=1,dpi=192]  output_1_.jpg[Q=100]
```

#### 試した結果

- PDFの内容がjpeg画像として保存された。(OK)
- ただし、PDFには存在する注釈が、jpeg画像には表示されていなかった。(NG)

[image: ghostscriptで変換すると注釈が表示される]
[image: libvipsで変換すると注釈が表示されない]

Comment: 参考までに、Ghostscript ではどのように抽出を行っていますか？

Comment: @cubick
ghostscript v9.54.0を使い、以下のようなコマンドを実行して抽出しました。

`gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNumRenderingThreads=2 -dNOGC -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r384 -dDownScaleFactor=2 -sDEVICE=jpeg -dJPEGQ=100 -dQFactor=0 -sOutputFile=./output.jpg ./input.pdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 結論

次のように libvips をコンパイルすれば、PDFを画像化する際に注釈を表示できます。
4行目(sed -z ~)を追加してします。

```
wget $VIPS_URL/v$VIPS_VERSION/vips-$VIPS_VERSION.tar.gz \
  && tar xf vips-$VIPS_VERSION.tar.gz \
  && cd vips-$VIPS_VERSION \
  && sed -z -i 's/FPDF_RenderPageBitmap[^;]*;/FPDF_RenderPageBitmap( bitmap, pdf->page, 0, 0, rect.width, rect.height, 0, 1 );/' ./libvips/foreign/pdfiumload.c \
  && ./configure --prefix $PREFIX \
  && make V=0 \
  && make install
```

libvips は PDFium の FPDF_RenderPageBitmap 関数を実行する際に、注釈を表示しないオプションを指定しています。 上は注釈を表示するオプションにソースコードを書き換えてコンパイルしています。

### PDFium

FPDF_RenderPageBitmap関数の最後の引数に、RenderFlags.FPDF_ANNOT=1 を指定して実行すると、PDFの注釈を表示するようです。

```
public static void FPDF_RenderPageBitmap(
    IntPtr bitmap,
    IntPtr page,
    int start_x,
    int start_y,
    int size_x,
    int size_y,
    PageRotate rotate,
    RenderFlags flags
)
```

https://pdfium.patagames.com/help/html/M_Patagames_Pdf_Pdfium_FPDF_RenderPageBitmap.htm

### libvips

libvips側のコードを確認すると、最後の引数が 0 になっており、アノテーションを表示しないオプションが指定されています。 最後の引数を 1 に変更することで、目的を達成できます。

libvips/foreign/pdfiumload.c

```
FPDF_RenderPageBitmap( bitmap, pdf->page, 
    0, 0, rect.width, rect.height,
    0, 0 );
```

https://github.com/libvips/libvips/blob/976db37f84b5ab2d77e85cf3b123f63f97c35d39/libvips/foreign/pdfiumload.c#L592

### libvips のコンパイル

```
sed -z -i 's/FPDF_RenderPageBitmap[^;]*;/FPDF_RenderPageBitmap( bitmap, pdf->page, 0, 0, rect.width, rect.height, 0, 1 );/' ./libvips/foreign/pdfiumload.c
```

上のコマンドで、次のように、最後の引数を 0 → 1 に変更しています。

```
FPDF_RenderPageBitmap( bitmap, pdf->page, 
    0, 0, rect.width, rect.height,
    0, 0 ); 
　　　　　　　↓
FPDF_RenderPageBitmap( bitmap, pdf->page, 0, 0, rect.width, rect.height, 0, 1 );
```

Comment: ありがとうございます、注釈を表示できました